# Cleaner way to check if sub-properties exist

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm basically trying to check if `lote.projeto.id_projeto == 123`

So when the sub-properties are not defined it produces `cannot read property` errors.

Checking each sub-property with this poor code seems to be the only way to avoid those errors.

```
if(lote['projeto']){
  if(lote['projeto']['id_projeto']){
    if(lote['projeto']['id_projeto'] == 123){
      // ...
    }
  }
}
```

Is there any easier/cleaner way to do that?

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#optional-chaining

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typescript 3.7 comes with the concept of ***Optional Chaining***
Read more from the [official documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#optional-chaining)

so, probably you can do this

`lote?.projeto?.id_projeto == 123`

If any sub attribute is missing, then the condition will be false.

If you are running on a older version of typescript you have no other way to add && conditions like below

```
(lote.projeto && lote.projeto.id_projeto && lote.projeto.id_projeto == 123)
```

Comment: in my package.json file it says `"typescript": "~3.1.6"`

Comment: [Nullish Coalescing](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#nullish-coalescing) is `foo ?? 3`, not `bar?.baz`

Comment: if (foo?.bar?.baz) { / ... }

Comment: Nullish Coalescing: `let x = foo ?? bar();` Optional Chaining: `foo?.bar?.baz` These are two similar but different concepts.

Answer (score 4):

Try to use `&&` operator:

```
if (lote['projeto']      
   && lote['projeto']['id_projeto'] == 123) {
   // ...        
}
```

[As mdn says about `&&`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators):

> Syntax: **expr1 && expr2**
>   If **expr1** can be converted to true,
>   returns **expr2**; else, returns **expr1**.

Comment: You can cut the second test in this safely, it’s redundant to first check if an id exists then check if it’s equal to something

Comment: @bryan60 You are absolutely right! Thanks! Updated!:)

Answer (score 1):

1. you don't need to test for the property being truthy before testing equality
2. you can use the new [Optional Chaining](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#optional-chaining) in Typescript 3.7 if you goal is to test for a value (vs. test for property existing so you can do something in an `else`)

```
if (lote.projeto?.id_projeto == 123) {
}
```

If your property names are determined at run-time, you can use the "optional element access" syntax

```
if (lote?.['projeto']?.['id_projeto'] == 123) {
}
```